# better way to reload chef cookbook after updating it

Tags: chef-infra

Everytime I make a change to the cookbook I'm working on (it's a fork of a provider) to get it into my vagrant run I have to:

1. Delete  `Berksfile.lock`
2. Delete  `.berskhelf` folder
3. Run     `vagrant provision` to get new files (but it errors)
4. Run     `vagrant reload` to get it to remount shared  folders (and to fix previous error)
5. Run     `vagrant provision` to actually run my cookbook and see what happens

There has to be a better way, can someone tell me of it? or is my only solution to make a batch file to do all that?

EDIT: I just made a batch script to do all that, but still I get the feeling I'm doing it wrong so could any one answer?

batch script:

```
del -f .\Berksfile.lock
del -f %HOME%\.berkshelf

vagrant provision
vagrant reload
vagrant provision
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? Just get it unders chef control, upload changes to your cookbook with knife and then download the changed with chef-client

Comment: I'm running it local, I push my cookbook to github and get it from there when I'm installing it, the problem is that without all those steps chef refuses to install the updated version.

Comment: If you are running it locally you should still be pushing out the cookbook, you could upload it as dev-version, and then download and install it with knife.

Comment: You don't even have to push it somewhere during development. Just a `vagrant provision`. You might want to try the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `path` source specifier (though from your comments it sounds like maybe you are using `git` or `github` which would, indeed, be non-optimal) all you should need to do is re-run the provision step. In general you should never have to remove the lockfile (exceptions made for when you change the `source` line) and you should very never remove the `.berkshelf` folder, that is equivalent to removing `$GEM_HOME` to force an upgrade. If you are having issues with it requesting a reload often, double check that you have the latest vagrant-berkshelf plugin.